# Limite de index com LIMIT

Tags: mysql

Eu nunca fui um expert em sql mas sempre virei, nada que uma googlada não tenha resolvido. Mas tenho uma dúvida que não achei informação sobre isso.

Recentemente eu fiz uns teste pra descobri porque um sql estava lento e deparei com a seguinte situação

```
select campo from tabela limit 0,150
```

a tabela tinha mais de 10mil regitros. Ai usei explain pra descobriu pq as vezes fica lento e as vezes não, e descobri q dependendo do valor do LIMIT o select usava o index e depois de um valor q não me recordo agora qual era, o index não era usado.

alguém sabe me explicar o porquê e se existem algum limite de uso do LIMIT

```
explain SELECT id, nome, email FROM tabela ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,20
```

saida do explain:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1      SIMPLE tabela index NULL PRIMARY 3 NULL 20

explain SELECT id, nome, email FROM tabela ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,820
```

saida do explain:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE tabela ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 14132 Using filesort
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, acho que não existem limites para o `LIMIT`!

Comment: A pergunta parece interessante, mas dê mais subsídios para quem sabe poder responder. O limite parece não existir, mas o por quê ele decidir usar o índice ou não é bem curioso. Mas só dá para responder com bastante informação sobre a situação. Sei lá, coloque as tabelas, como estão os dados, mostre estatísticas, o resultado do `EXPLAIN`. Do jeito que está só você pode responder.

Comment: ok, estou editando com os exemplos exatos e as respostas do explain na pergunta

Comment: não consegui editar a pergunta completei abaixo

Comment: Essa é a consulta lenta? pela quantia de registros e pela consulta não era para ter esse tipo de problema.

Comment: mas por que se aumento os valores em LIMIT o index não é utilizado? tem algum motivo pra isso?

Answer (score 4):

Muitas vezes o *query planner* percebe que a performance de uma leitura sequencial em disco sai mais "barata" para o sistema do que ficar consultando o índice e fazendo leituras aleatórias.

Sem índice, o DB pode ir varrendo os registros (mesmo fora de ordem), e pegando só o que interessa (e eventualmente já ordenando na saída):

```
SELECT * FROM x BETWEEN( 3, 10 )

0 > 1 > 8 > 5 > 128 > 2 > 882 > 9 > 7 > 11 > 92 > 6 > 4 > 10 > 3 ...
        |   |                   |   |             |   |   |    |
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

No caso acima, a query "olha" um por um, compara, e vai acumulando o que interessa.

Quando você usa um limit baixo, por exemplo 3, compensa usar o índice, apesar do overhead da consulta ao mesmo e leitura aleatória

```
SELECT * FROM x BETWEEN( 3, 10 ) LIMIT 4

INDICE: 0, 1, 2, 3 (start), 4, 5, 6 (stop), 7, 8, 9, 11, 92 ...
BUSCA:           ->         -> <-  ->
DB:     0 > 1 > 8 > 5 > 128 > 2 > 882 > 9 > 7 > 11 > 92 > 6 > 4 > 10 > 3 ...
```

No caso acima, como são poucos, compensa começar pelo índice, pegar o primeiro, achar onde está no disco, ler aquela parte dos dados (lembrando que se fosse só o valor da coluna indexada nem precisaria do DB, bastaria o índice), ir para o próximo do índice, localizar os dados no DB, ler os dados, voltar ao indice novalmente para ver o próximo, ler os dados do DB... etc.

Note que no primeiro caso, não tem esse "vai e vem" no índice, pois pela quantidade não compensa ficar lendo mil pedaços separados do arquivo que contem os dados, pois a leitura sequencial dos mesmos usualmente é mais rápida.

No segundo caso, é pouca informação, então fazer esse "vai e vem" compensa, pois mesmo com as leituras aleatórias, ainda vão ser lidos bem menos dados do que o DB todo.

Estou assumindo as bases de dados mais comuns, trabalhando em HDs normais. Tem DBs que fazem uma especialização para acesso em memória ou SSDs. Inclusive, o *query planner* toma estas decisões baseado em uma série de estatísticas, que podem não dar o melhor resultado em todas as situações, mas geralmente na maioria delas o ganho justifica. O que é importante entender é que alguém programou ele desta forma, e com grande probabilidade de ter feito uma quantidade absurda de testes para melhorar seu funcionamento.

### Do manual do MySQL

Veja, por exemplo, nestes links:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html <sup>(en)</sup>
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html <sup>(en)</sup>

Destaque para esta linha:

> *You are comparing indexed columns with constant values and MySQL has calculated (based on the index tree) that the constants cover too large a part of the table and that a table scan would be faster.*
>
> Você está comparando colunas indexadas com valores constantes, e o MySQL calculou, baseado na árvore de índice, que elas cobrem uma parte tão grande da tabela, que escaneá-la diretamente será mais rápido.

E esta:

> *You are using a key with low cardinality (many rows match the key value) through another column. In this case, MySQL assumes that by using the key it probably will do many key lookups and that a table scan would be faster.*
>
> Você está usando uma chave com baixa cardinalidade (muitas linhas batem com o valor da chave) através de outra coluna. Neste caso, o MySQL assume que usando a chave, vai fazer muitas buscas pelas mesmas, e que é mais rápido escanear a tabela.

Apesar de não serem o cenário exato do LIMIT, a mesma lógica se aplica.